# Swiper.JS Rows: 2 is stacking everything resulting in infinite rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, swiper.js

I am trying to integrate SwiperJS into a wordpress theme I am creating. I am trying to create a slider with two rows, and it is basically just like their demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x3ty9k?file=/index.html:912-955

But when I follow the demo, I am left with every slide stacking on top of each other, which is obviously more than 2 rows (12 rows in total right now, and could increase if I add more slides). The weirdest part about it is that the slider registers that there SHOULD be more "pages", and the left/right buttons and pagination still work (but pressing next just brings you to a blank page of the slider).

**The Problem:** 
Rows are stacking when following the documentation for SwiperJS.

**What I Have tried:**

- Gone through my CSS to alter any flex displays, gotten rid of anything that could affect the slider layout
- tried following https://codepen.io/andreacazzola90/pen/ZEBBXqm for a different method of obtaining multi rows with SwiperJS
- Changed around HTML to try the slider with more and less wrappers.

**The JavaScript:**

```
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    grid: {
      rows: 2
    },
    spaceBetween: 30,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
  });
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="conference-speakers-cards-container container swiper-wrapper" data-chunksize="6">
        <?php 

        if ( !function_exists('wpeventin')) {
            echo 'Please Install and Activate the WP Event Solution plugin in order to use the Speakers Section';
        } else {
            wp_reset_query();
            $speaker_array = [];
            $args = [
                'post_type' => 'etn-speaker',
                'posts_per_page' => -1 
            ];

            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                while($the_query->have_posts()) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    $speaker_avatar = apply_filters("etn/speakers/avatar", \Wpeventin::assets_url() . "images/avatar.jpg");
                    $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                    $speaker_data = [
                        'speaker_name' => apply_filters('etn_speaker_title', get_the_title()),
                        'speaker_designation' => $post_meta["etn_speaker_designation"][0],
                        'speaker_thumbnail' => has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : $speaker_avatar,
                        'speaker_permalink' => get_the_permalink()
                    ];
                    
                    array_push($speaker_array, $speaker_data);
                }
            }

            //<!-- SPEAKER CARD TEMPLATE -->
            foreach($speaker_array as $speaker) { ;?>

                
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="<?php echo $speaker['speaker_permalink']; ?>">
                        <div class="conference-speaker-card-wrapper ">
                            <div class="speaker-card-avatar-wrapper">
                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $speaker['speaker_thumbnail'] ); ?>" alt="Picture of <?php echo $speaker['speaker_name']; ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="speaker-card-info-wrapper">
                                <div class="speaker-card-title"><?php echo $speaker['speaker_name']; ?></div>
                                <div class="speaker-card-designation"><?php echo $speaker['speaker_designation']; ?></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            
            <?php
            } ?>
        <?php
        } 
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

**The SCSS:**

```
.conference-speakers-container {
    //display: flex;
    //flex-direction: column;
    //min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;

    .conference-speaker-slider-left-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        font-size: 35px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50px;
        transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
        color: #909090;
        border: 2px solid #909090;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1010;
        padding-top: 5px;

        @include mobile {
            left: 15px;
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
    }

    .conference-speaker-slider-right-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        font-size: 35px;
        top: 50%;
        right: 50px;
        transform: translate(50%, 50%);
        color: #909090;
        border: 2px solid #909090;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1010;
        padding-top: 5px;

        .conference-speaker-slider-right-arrow:hover {
            color: $hover-color;
        }

        @include mobile {
            right: 15px;
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
    }

    .conference-speakers-title-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: white;
        height: 125px;

        .title-word-blue {
            color: $main-color;
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .title-word-black {
            color: black;
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }

    .conference-speakers {
        //height: calc(100vh - 125px);
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        //display: flex;
        //justify-content: center;
        //align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .mySwiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;

        .conference-speakers-cards-container {
            //swiper-wrapper
            //display: flex;
            //justify-content: center;
            //gap: 1em;
            //flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding-bottom: 125px;
            padding-top: 50px;
            //overflow: hidden;
            //min-width: calc(100% - 120px);
            margin: auto;
    
            .swiper-slide {
                //margin: auto;
                //min-width: 100%;
                //display: flex;
                //justify-content: center;
                //align-items: center;
                max-width: 344px;
                height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2) !important;
                
                a {
                    //display: inline-block;
                    .conference-speaker-card-wrapper {
                        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 10px 15px -3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 6px -2px;
                        max-width: 344px;
                        &:hover {
                            transform: scale(1.02);
                            transition: .25s;
                            .speaker-card-info-wrapper {
                                .speaker-card-title {
                                    color: #0073AE;
                                    text-decoration: underline;
                                    transition: .25s;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .speaker-card-avatar-wrapper {
                            height: 344px;
                            img {
                                height: 344px;
                                width: 100%;
                                object-fit: cover;
                                object-position: center;
                            }
                        }
            
                        .speaker-card-info-wrapper {
                            background-color: white;
                            color: #2C344A;
                            padding: 10px;
                            text-align: center;
            
                            .speaker-card-title {
                                font-size: 21px;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                margin-bottom: -5px;
                            }
                            .speaker-card-designation {
                                font-size: 15px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, there's a lot commented out, and that's because I'm trying to figure this out hahah

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
slidesPerColumn: 2
```

instead

```
grid: {
      rows: 2
    }
```

The final slider code should be

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
  });
```

Reference: [codepen.io/multi-row](https://codepen.io/kadams277/pen/mZaXee)